# Particular solution of partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Need help solving this.

> Find the particular solution of the differential equation $$u_y = (5x + 2)u$$ that satisfies the data $u(x, x^2) = x^3$.

I usually try to find the characteristic equation but I can only see $u_y$ here.

Comment: How is this a differential equation?  I don’t see any differentials here.  I’m confused.

Comment: It is a partial differential equation

Comment: @RadialArmSaw The subscript notation for differentials is particularly aggravating to me as well.

Comment: @K.defaoite It is weird.  I’ve never ever seen differentials or partial differentials denoted that way.

Comment: I have seen partial differentials written this way; to me the notation makes perfect sense but for the avoidance of doubt I would write the dependent variables for $u$, as as far as we know $u$ could be a function of $4$ vaiables $u(x, y, z, w)$ (I am sure it is just $x$ and $y$).

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Frustratingly, although very misleading, the notation is commonly used. Personally I prefer $\partial_x^n$ representing $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}$ and likewise $\mathrm{D}_x^n$ representing $\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

We treat is as an ODE, using a suitable integral factor:
$$
u_y(x,y)=(5x+2)u(x,y)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \mathrm{e}^{-(5x+2)y}
u_y(x,y)-\mathrm{e}^{-(5x+2)y}(5x+2)u(x,y)=0
\\ \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-(5x+2)y}u(x,y)\right)=0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\mathrm{e}^{-(5x+2)y}u(x,y)=f(x)
$$
for some function $f(x)$ to be found.

Hence
$$
u(x,y)=\mathrm{e}^{(5x+2)y}f(x).
$$
Now, $u(x,x^2)=x^3$, provides that
$$
x^3=u(x,x^2)=\mathrm{e}^{(5x+2)x^2}f(x)
$$
and hence
$$
f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-(5x+2)x^2}x^3
$$
Altogether
$$
u(x,y)=\mathrm{e}^{(5x+2)y}f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{(5x+2)y}\mathrm{e}^{-(5x+2)x^2}x^3=
\mathrm{e}^{(5x+2)(y-x^2)}x^3.
$$